# .desktop file works when opened from /usr/share/applications but not from Slingshot or Plank

Tags: plank, slingshot, app-shortcuts

I made a .desktop file so I could run an .sh file from the Plank dock. It is as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Drive
Icon=/home/finn/Programs/drive-logo.png
Exec=/home/finn/Programs/grive.sh
```

It links to this .sh script, which is currently a placeholder:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Drive
mkdir itworked
```

The last line will be replaced with `grive` once I get it working. At the moment it just makes a folder so I can see if the script ran successfully. I made it executable with `sudo chmod +x drive.desktop` while in /usr/share/applications. Currently it works perfectly if I navigate to  /usr/share/applications in the Files browser and double-click on the icon. It shows up in the Slingshot applications menu, and I can drag it to the Plank dock, but when I try click and open it from either of these places it does nothing. Weirdly, if I open Files as Administrator and then try open it from there it also does nothing. I've tried setting the permissions to match other applications, or just be fully open to everyone, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed the third line to `terminal=false` and it works now, which is a shame because I wanted to have the terminal open when the drive syncs, but I guess you can't have everything.

Looks like it's been a bug for a few years, not really eOS's fault:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-terminal/+bug/1176526
https://bugs.launchpad.net/slingshot/+bug/1066462